# Get multiple active users in a session/Google sheets workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have managed to get Active user in the session/Google workbook using the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(). However, is there a way to get multiple active users using the spreadsheet? For eg. 'User A' working on Sheet1 and 'User B' working on Sheet2. I would like to get email addresses of User A and User B.

Answer (score 0):

### You can create a log sheet that is being populated each time a user performs an edit

Sample:

```js
function bindMeOnInstallableOnEditTrigger(e){
  var logsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("YYY");
  var user = e.user;
  var activeSheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  logsheet.appendRow([new Date(), user, "edited sheet", activeSheetName]);
}
```

Bind this function to an installable trigger as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your method. e.user is giving me an empty string.

Comment: Does the user belong to your domain? See [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser): ` If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string.`.